# Understanding caching strategies of a dynamically generated search page

Tags: http-headers, html, dynamically-generated, http-caching

While studying the caching strategies adopted by various search engine websites and Stackoverflow itself, I can't help but notice the subtle differences in the response headers:

**Google Search**

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Expires: -1
```

**Yahoo Search**

```
Cache-Control: private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100
```

**Stackoverflow Search**

```
Cache-Control: private
```

There must be some logical explanation behind the settings adopted. Can someone care to explain the differences so that everyone of us can learn and benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC2616 HTTP/1.1 Header Field Definitions, 14.9.1 What is Cacheable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

```
private
   Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single
   user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache. This allows an origin server
   to state that the specified parts of the response are intended for only one
   user and are not a valid response for requests by other users. A private
   (non-shared) cache MAY cache the response.
```

`max-age=0` means that it may be cached up to 0 seconds. The value zero would mean that no caching should be performed.

`Expires=-1` should be ignored when there's a `max-age` present, and -1 is an invalid date and should be parsed as a value in the past (meaning already expired).

From [RFC2616 HTTP/1.1 Header Field Definitions, 14.21 Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21):

```
Note: if a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-age directive
      (see section 14.9.3), that directive overrides the Expires field

HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats, especially
including the value "0", as in the past (i.e., "already expired").
```

The `Connection: Keep-Alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100` configures settings for [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). All connections using HTTP/1.1 are persistent unless otherwise specified, but these headers change the actual timeout values instead of using the browsers default (which varies greatly).

Comment: Good answer. To make it complete, can you explain why max-age=0 is set for Google while Yahoo and Stackoverflow leaves it unset? And how does the cache behaves if max-age is not set?

Comment: Yahoo (se.search.yahoo.com) sends `private, max-age=0, no-cache` to me. I don't know why StackOverflow doesn't specify max-age, it does currently allow the browser to cache the result page. Ask on Meta!